# aws cli to update dynamo db replacing instead of adding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I have a AWS cli command to update item in dynamo db table :

> aws dynamodb update-item --table-name pib-deployments --key
>   '{"stackname": { "S": "factiva_search"}}' --update-expression 'SET
>   githuburl = :gu, ldapCommaSepList = :ll, lz = :lz, slackChannelName =
>   :scn, slackToken = :st' --expression-attribute-values
>   '{":gu":{"S":"https://github.com/djin-infrastructure/djin_acntsvc_factiva_search.git"},":ll":{"S":"gillinwar"}, ":scn":{"S":"search-on-aws-tf-jobs"},
>   ":st":{"S":"MjcAvMeG9d2CExW6GzSURMqa"},
>   ":lz":{"M":{"cntsvc":{"M":{"prod":{"M":{"blue":{"M":{"virginia":{"M":{"approver":{"S":"lana"},"last_modified":{"S":"08/18/2017 11:00:29.450"},"status":{"S":"up"}}}}}}}}}}}}'
>   --return-values ALL_NEW

this gives me :

```
{
  "githuburl": "https://github.com/djin-infrastructure/djin_acntsvc_factiva_search.git",
  "ldapCommaSepList": "gillinwar",
  "lz": {
    "cntsvc": {
      "prod": {
        "blue": {
          "virginia": {
            "approver": "lana",
            "last_modified": "08/18/2017 11:00:29.450",
            "status": "up"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "slackChannelName": "search-on-aws-tf-jobs",
  "slackToken": "MjcAvMeG9d2CExW6GzSURMqa",
  "stackname": "factiva_search"
}
```

which is what I need. Now I need to update the table by adding another key under `cntsvc`so I use:

> aws dynamodb update-item --table-name pib-deployments --key
>   '{"stackname": { "S": "factiva_search"}}' --update-expression 'SET
>   githuburl = :gu, ldapCommaSepList = :ll, lz = :lz, slackChannelName =
>   :scn, slackToken = :st' --expression-attribute-values
>   '{":gu":{"S":"https://github.com/djin-infrastructure/djin_acntsvc_factiva_search.git"},":ll":{"S":"gillinwar"}, ":scn":{"S":"search-on-aws-tf-jobs"},
>   ":st":{"S":"MjcAvMeG9d2CExW6GzSURMqa"},
>   ":lz":{"M":{"cntsvc":{"M":{"stag":{"M":{"blue":{"M":{"virginia":{"M":{"approver":{"S":"lana"},"last_modified":{"S":"08/18/2017 11:00:29.450"},"status":{"S":"up"}}}}}}}}}}}}'
>   --return-values ALL_NEW

Notice the only difference between the cli is prod becomes stag and I expect the following tree :

```
{  
   "githuburl":"https://github.com/djin-infrastructure/djin_acntsvc_factiva_search.git",
   "ldapCommaSepList":"gillingwar",
   "lz":{  
      "cntsvc":{  
         "prod":{  
            "blue":{  
               "virginia":{  
                  "approver":"lana",
                  "last_modified":"08/18/2017 11:00:29.450",
                  "status":"up"
               }
            }
         },
         "stag":{  
            "blue":{  
               "virginia":{  
                  "approver":"lana",
                  "last_modified":"08/18/2017 11:00:29.450",
                  "status":"up"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "slackChannelName":"search-on-aws-tf-jobs",
   "slackToken":"MjcAvMeG9d2CExW6GzSURMqa",
   "stackname":"factiva_search"
}
```

but what I end up getting is :

```
{
  "githuburl": "https://github.com/djin-infrastructure/djin_acntsvc_factiva_search.git",
  "ldapCommaSepList": "gillingwar",
  "lz": {
    "cntsvc": {
      "stag": {
        "blue": {
          "virginia": {
            "approver": "lana",
            "last_modified": "08/18/2017 11:00:29.450",
            "status": "up"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "slackChannelName": "search-on-aws-tf-jobs",
  "slackToken": "MjcAvMeG9d2CExW6GzSURMqa",
  "stackname": "factiva_search"
}
```

basically my tree completely replaces with the new tree instead of adding to it. Any ideas why and how to resolve ?

Comment: Did you just published some credentials on internet? `slackToken` smells like one.

Comment: You *are* overwriting the entire data. To add just the `stag` part try in this direction `SET lz.cntsvc.stag = :justStagPart`. Dont send the things which do not need to be updated, the token for instance. Also, no, none of us are required to have any clue of what anyone copypasted.